# merge two columns in dataframe

Tags: merge

I have a df that I want to have two columns combined or merged (I am not sure of the correct term) by grouping of another column.

Here is my df

```
> print(BC_data)
             Treatment  Day    LB      PCA
Day2F1       Untreated   2  4400000 10900000
Day2F2       Untreated   2  5800000  5200000
Day2F3       Untreated   2  5700000  5900000
Day2F4           Metro   2 13100000 11500000
Day2F5           Metro   2  9600000  9100000
Day2F6           Metro   2  6900000  9700000
Day2F7             Pen   2 11400000  5100000
Day2F8             Pen   2  8000000  7300000
Day2F9             Pen   2  6300000  9300000
Day2F10            Rif   2   600000  4600000
Day2F11            Rif   2   400000 25000000
```

I would like to have the column LB and PCA put together in one column and grouped by days. to become something like this

```
             Treatment   Day LB-PCA
Day2F1       Untreated   2  4400000
Day2F2       Untreated   2  5800000
Day2F3       Untreated   2  5700000
Day2F1       Untreated   2  10900000
Day2F2       Untreated   2  5200000
Day2F3       Untreated   2  5900000
......
```

Can any one help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you are using R, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate the records in two steps. First, select all records in the original df but renaming column LB as LB-PCA. Next, concatenate all rows in the original df but now using PCA as LB-PCA. Finally, sort if needed.